# sending images to server via json

Tags: ios, json, nsdata

I am posting data to a server from my ipad using json. But along with my data, i need to be able to send images aswell. I tried to add my image data to a dictionary and parse that into json, but json doesnt like nscfdata. What would be the easiest way i can post my images to the server? from other posts related to this topic, people have been converting to base64. Would i have to do that, or is there another easier or faster way? if i have to encode to base64 is there any tutorial on that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: that doesnt really help me, im sending from ipad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I convert it to base64. Check out this tutorial to get started!

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Example:

```
NSImage *image = // some image
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *base64EncodedString = [data base64EncodedString];
```

You can then send the string via JSON.

Comment: can you share an example of how you convert image data as nsdata to base64 string?